# How realise logic subl in console

Tags: linux, terminal, console

everyone

Please, tell me. I will want realise logic subl3 in terminal on linux. I use ubuntu, but no matter. When i call symbol `"` or `(` in subl my cursor write two symbol and return cursor on one symbol back.

Comment: What's _subl3_?

Comment: This is sublime text 3